# xpath choose first table

Tags: xpath, mechanize

I have xpath

```
page.search("//table[@class='campaign']//table")
```

which returns two tables.

I need to choose only first table. This line doesn't work:

```
page.search("//table[@class='campaign']//table[1]")
```

How to choose only first table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bugged me, too. I still don't exactly know why your solution does not work. However, this should:

```
page.search("//table[@class='campaign']/descendant::table[1]")
```

**EDIT**: As [the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) say,

> "The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location
>   path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant
>   para element; the former selects all descendant para elements that are
>   the first para children of their parents."

Thanks to your question, I finally understood why this works this way :). So, depending on your structure and needs, this should work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an XPath expression to select the first matching element, you can either find all of them and then pare it down:

```
first_table = page.search("//table[@class='campaign']//table").first
```

...or better yet, select only the first by using [`at`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html#method-i-at):

```
first_table = page.at("//table[@class='campaign']//table")
```

Note also that your expression can be found more simply by using the CSS selector syntax:

```
first_table = page.at("table.campaign table")
```